# Windows Credential Provider - store password

Tags: credential-providers

I wrote a simple Credential Provider to provide an alternative to the username/password combination.
Finally (after checking my 2-factor stuff) I have to provide username and password via `ICredentialProviderCredential.GetSerialization`. This works pretty fine.

**But where to store the password?** Sure I could store it in the registry, perhaps also encrypted. But that is not secure, to decrypt it I would need a key that key is on the system and can be leaked. So an attacker will be able to decrypt the password. Even worse: when the user changes his password, my copy will become invalid!
I would expect windows to handle this. So after kind of initialization (e.g. after once successfully providing the password in my provider) the system should store the information that 'UserA' has been authorized once and in the future windows should provide an authentication package via `ICredentialProvider.SetSerialization` (containing only the valid hash and username).

Is there such a functionality, or do I have to store the password myself?

Comment: Have a look at [CryptProtectData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata) DPAPI.

Comment: @Alexander - sure there are some ways to encrypt that, but this still does not solve the password change issue. There should be a smarter way.

Comment: *after checking my 2-factor stuff* - and what is on first factor ? no such functionality. and exist different login variants. not all use password. all you need design yourself

Comment: @RbMm - there is a password and a token, but the password is a different one. The idea is to identify several users and log them in always with 'Administrator'. So the user should not know the windows password. Similar to the PIN CP, where the user need not know the password.

Comment: in case PIN - password stored in file, encrypted by this pin. if want without password - write own authentication package which based on your serialization return info for *Administrator* account